# как можно, во время работы программы, подгружать ресурсы из фала .unitypackage?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во время работы приложение сервер должен прислать AssetBundle и файл с расширением .unitypackage, в котором хранится база данных с маркерами. 
Можно ли во время работы приложения распаковать файл .unitypackage и если можно, то как это сделать ?

[image: Я пробовал пользоваться методом ImportPackage класса AssetDatabase, но он не заработал (только если не поместить его в папку Editor, но в этом случае он будет расцениваться ка скрипт редактора Unity).]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы типа unitypackage вы можете использовать только в редакторе. Единственное api, работающее с ними - [AssetDatabase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html), класс, доступный только в редакторе unity.

Как вариант решения, вы можете попробовать пересылать информацию о маркерах в текстовом формате, например json, и использовать встроенный [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) для работы с ним. Либо попробовать зашить нужный вам ресурс в AssetBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо !!! 
В таком случае отсюда вытекает другая проблема. Мне нужно упаковать два файла с расширением .xml и .dat. Когда я пытаюсь это сделать, в консоле появляются следующие warining'и:

1. Unrecognized assets cannot be included in AssetBundles: "Assets/StreamingAssets/Vuforia/AR_Demo.xml".
   UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles(String, BuildAssetBundleOptions, BuildTarget)
   BuildAssetBundle:BuildAssetBundles() (at Assets/Editor/BuildAssetBundle.cs:15)
2. Unrecognized assets cannot be included in AssetBundles: "Assets/StreamingAssets/Vuforia/AR_Demo.dat".
   UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles(String, BuildAssetBundleOptions, BuildTarget)
   BuildAssetBundle:BuildAssetBundles() (at Assets/Editor/BuildAssetBundle.cs:15)
3. No AssetBundle has been set for this build.
   UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles(String, BuildAssetBundleOptions, BuildTarget)
   BuildAssetBundle:BuildAssetBundles() (at Assets/Editor/BuildAssetBundle.cs:15)

AssetBundle я создаю следующим образом (BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(path, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux)).

Comment: 1) Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный. 2) Для того, чтобы уточнить детали по ответу, оформите их как комментарий к ответу, а не отдельный ответ. 3) по поводу вашей проблемы - посмотрите как выимпортировали xml и dat файлы в проект - если как скрипт - то вы не сможете добавить их в бандлы так как в бандлы можно добавлять только определенные типы ресурсов [см документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html), возможно если вы импортируете их как TextAsset, то сможете положить в бандл

Comment: Спасибо ) Вы мне очень помогли.